# gui not functioning properly

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

i am getting a clean compile but when i run it and type in a name and click "add" it just gives me the error message "invalid entry" when it is supposed to just add it to the arraylist and thats it. what happened?

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class FinalB extends JFrame{
 private static int WIDTH = 500;
 private static int HEIGHT = 250;
 private static String nameEntered;
 private static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

 private int row = 20;

 private JTextField textF = new JTextField(20);
 private JButton addB, removeB, searchB, printB;
 private JButton exitB;
 private ButtonEventHandler eventHandler;

 public FinalB(){
 setTitle("Very Important List");
 setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

 Container pane = getContentPane();

 exitB = new JButton("Exit");
 addB = new JButton("Add");
 removeB = new JButton("Remove");
 searchB = new JButton("Search");
 printB = new JButton("print list");

 JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter a Name:");
  label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
  pane.add(label);
  label.setLocation(0,50);
  label.setSize(200, 30);
  label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

 eventHandler = new ButtonEventHandler();
 exitB.addActionListener(eventHandler);
 addB.addActionListener(eventHandler);
 removeB.addActionListener(eventHandler);
 searchB.addActionListener(eventHandler);
 printB.addActionListener(eventHandler);

 pane.setLayout(null); //sets pane to null

 //set the buttons (500,250)
 exitB.setLocation(125,150);
 addB.setLocation(125,100);
 removeB.setLocation(205,100);
 searchB.setLocation(300,100);
 printB.setLocation(303,150);
 textF.setLocation (125,50);

 //set size of buttons
 exitB.setSize(90, 30);
 addB.setSize(75, 30);
 removeB.setSize(90, 30);
 searchB.setSize(90, 30);
 printB.setSize(90, 30);
 textF.setSize(268,30);

 //add them to the pane
 pane.add(exitB);
 pane.add(addB);
 pane.add(removeB);
 pane.add(searchB);
 pane.add(printB);
 pane.add(textF);

 setVisible(true);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}//ends constructor

private class ButtonEventHandler implements ActionListener{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  String text = textF.getText();
  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Add")){
   list.add(text);
  }
  else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"invalid entry","invalid entry",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Remove")){
   list.remove(text);
  }
  else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"invalid entry","invalid entry",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Print list")){ 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),list,"Printed list",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"invalid entry","invalid entry",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Search")){
   ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(String searchVal : list){
   if(searchVal.matches(text)){
   newList.add(searchVal);
   }
  }
 }
```

else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"invalid entry","invalid entry",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
     if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit"))
                     System.exit(0);

} 
  }

}

Comment: What is this `list<String>`. Look at the method `showMessageDialog()` again in JavaDoc.

Comment: The compiler tells you right there what is wrong. I recommend reading up on the basics of Java.

Comment: i know that part is wrong i had it differently but just tried anything i could before i gave up and put it on here.

Comment: What error? What's wrong?

Comment: i figured it out to get it to compile now, however there must be errors in my code because it just says "invalid entry" whenever i enter a name like i said it should but it should only say that if i dont enter a name

Comment: Don't use `null` layouts. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen. Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...

Answer (score 2):

Your `add` command works fine, the problem is with your `if` statements...

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add")) {
    list.add(text);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "invalid entry", "invalid entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Remove")) {
    list.remove(text);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "invalid entry", "invalid entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Print list")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), list, "Printed list", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "invalid entry", "invalid entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Basically what's happening is the code is going...

- "if add" do list.add...
- "if remove", "else" show error message
- "if print", "else" show error message

So, basically, each `if` branch is been executed, instead, you should be using `if-else` statements...

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add")) {
    list.add(text);
} else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Remove")) {
    list.remove(text);
} else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Print list")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), list, "Printed list", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "invalid entry", "invalid entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Don't use `null` layouts. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen.

Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but off the cuff, `list<String>` looks incorrect - it should be upper case `List<String>` as java is case sensitive.

As a quick second note, I'd be surprised if a dialog could take an array list rather than just a string.  You might want to look into sending `Arrays.toString(your_array_list.toArray())` instead as that gives you a real string to print.

I admittedly didn't read through all the code though; this is just a quick answer :)

Comment: The `Arrays` class is for...arrays :)

Comment: Meh, Arrays, StringUtils, guava libraries, joins, it's all a matter of what you already imported unless its performance critical :)

Comment: yes i fixed that part i believe but it wont function properly

Comment: it even says invalid entry when i hit the exit button